How to Load a ‘Learner’ Model with a Custom Loss Function in a Flask Application
I am currently working on loading a learner model from a pickle file. This model includes a custom loss function and needs to be integrated into a Flask application. The loss function is in the same file as the Flask app.
However, I keep encountering the following error:
Custom classes or functions exported with your `Learner` not available in namespace.\Re-declare/import before loading:
    Can't get attribute 'combined_loss' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Meteor\\flask_app\\venv\\Scripts\\flask.exe\\__main__.py'>

